# Airflow end_date error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I want to add an end_date to my DAG however, when I run the specific DAG I get the above error. It seems odd because I can update the startdate in the same format but not the enddate.

Here is a sample of my code below.

```
default_args = base_args.copy()
default_args['end_date'] = datetime(2020, 5, 5)
dag = DAG(
    dag_name,
    catchup=True,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval
)
with dag:
    extract = BashOperator(
            task_id=dag_name
         )
```

And here is the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 413, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/stevepak/Desktop/airflow/Dags/braintree/braintree_transactions_v3.py", line 40, in <module>
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval
  File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 3087, in __init__
    timezone.convert_to_utc(self.default_args['end_date'])
  File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/timezone.py", line 92, in convert_to_utc
    if not is_localized(value):
  File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/timezone.py", line 38, in is_localized
    return value.utcoffset() is not None
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/airflow/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 647, in test
    dag = dag or get_dag(args)
  File "/Users/steve/.virtualenvs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 145, in get_dag
    'parse.'.format(args.dag_id))
```

Comment: are you sure that you don't have a comma by mistake after `datetime(2020, 5, 5)`?

Comment: @Gabip I am positive that its not a comma mistake

Comment: Can you post entire DAG for us to reproduce please, obfuscate the logic if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some extra comma in the code creates this. Especially in the following line:

Before fix:

```
import pendulum
local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
date = datetime(2021, 8, 3, tzinfo=local_tz),
```

Had similar issue. It was extra "," that was creating the issue.

After Fix:

```
import pendulum
local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
date = datetime(2021, 8, 3, tzinfo=local_tz)
```